# Scala Error - Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type File

Tags: scala, exception

I have the following code:

```
var tempLastFileCreated: File = try {
  files(0)
} catch {
  case e: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => ???
}
```

where `files` is `val files: Array[File] = dir.listFiles()`

Now whatever I give in `case e` I get the message `Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type File`

I understand that the right hand part of the `=>` has to be something which is of type `File`.

Can anyone tell me what to put there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are promising that `tempLastFileCreated` is a `File`, therefore it cannot also be a `Unit` or a `String`, etc.  You have a couple options. You could use a `Option[File]` instead:

```
val tempLastFileCreated: Option[File] = try {
      Some(files(0))
    }
    catch {
      case e: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => None
    }
```

Or if you wanted to store an error message, for example, another option is to use `Either`:

```
val tempLastFileCreated: Either[String, File] = try {
      Right(files(0))
    }
    catch {
      case e: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => Left("index out of bounds!")
    }
```

Whatever bests suits your needs. You might want to take a look at Scala's `scala.util.Try` data type, which is safer. For example,

```
val tempLastFileCreated: Option[File] = Try(files(0)) match {
  case Success(file) => Some(file)
  case Failure(throwable) => None //or whatever
}
```

Comment: How about `.toEither` and `.toOption` on a `Try`?

Comment: This does solve the problem but in a later part I used `tempLastFileCreated.lastModified()` which gives rise to problems no matter what I use whether it's `Option[File]` or `Either[String, File]`

Comment: @rbh-93 The problem is that you not longer have a `File` but an `Option[File]` or a `Either[String, File]` it is like trying to sum a `String` - it is a different data type, it has different methods... The idea behind abstractions like **Try**, **Option** and **Either** is to force the caller of the method to deal with errors, there are a couple of ways to do so, like: using any kind of `getOrElse` to retrieve the value given a _default_ if the value is missing, using pattern matching to perform different actions for values and errors, or using higher order functions like `map` on them.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I understand the error now. Sorry if my questions sound quite stupid but I am very new to Scala. Is it possible to retain the `lastModified()` functionality while at the same time implementing exception handling of `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @rbh-93 No problem is okey, we all are learning something _(Sorry if I sounded harsh, it was not my intention - English is not my native language, and I always had the impression I sound aggressive in it)_. Regarding your question, it depends in what you mean with _"Error handling"_, more specifically who should deal with the error? Maybe `tempLastFileCreated` should always be a file, thus you may need to handle the error there using `try / catch` or `Try`, to provide a default value if something went wrong.

Comment: Maybe you want an external caller to deal with the error, then use **Either** or **Option** together with the  [`map` _function_](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html#map[B1](f:B=%3EB1):scala.util.Either[A,B1]) which allows you to process the element inside the **Effect** ignoring the side-effect that they may not exist, and return to the caller the abstraction, so he/she has to deal with the error.

Comment: Or maybe, you only want to log the error and let the program crash... or crash until some far away point _(probably the main, to gracefully shutdown other resources)_, in that case just catch the exception using `try / catch`, do your logging logic and rethrow it... this may be seen very **Java** and many people would disagree, but a fatal error should always crash your app. - Anyways, these comments are becoming very long, I hope they help you. If you have more doubts, google about the topic, there is plenty of info, and if you have troubles ask another question ;)